# Is GWT W3C compliant?

Tags: html, gwt, w3c

We are about to start some GWT project and I am investigating this technology a bit. One question that comes to my mind : is gwt generated page w3c compliant?

I had a look at gwt showcase and surprisingly its not validating as proper HTML

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgwt.google.com%2Fsamples%2FShowcase%2FShowcase.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML+4.01+Strict&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

Would anybody with GWT experience like to share his opinion?

thx
w

Comment: In your example, the validator is only checking the HTML before GWT JavaScript code generates the vast majority (probably upwards of 99%) of the actual HTML of the page. The warnings and errors you're seeing are but a small sign of things to come...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, GWT hasn't focused on producing standards-compliant HTML. Instead, it produces HTML that works. The problem is that browsers haven't been standards-compliant. As the browsers are now moving closer (in some cases) to standards, you'll find that GWT is going to produce more compliant output.

So, no, your GWT application most likely will not pass any HTML validation attempts. But it will work more consistently across browsers than compliant HTML.

Comment: Addendum to this: GWT goes out of its way to handle browser oddities, so it uses lots of invalid Javascript and HTML tricks to hide things from certain browsers and not others (which isn't supposed to really be allowed).

Comment: @haldean What sort of "tricks" do you have in mind? GWT produces different JS for each browser engine. Except for a few "soft" permutations, the user just downloads the code they need for their browser, so there really isn't anything to "hide."

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood then. I thought they were using CSS hacks to get IE and co. to work correctly?

Comment: @isaac My problem is that application we are about to develop will be shipped to a number of customers. So it means that every time new browser/version comes out we need to test our code and ship new version to our customers if it didn't work. Not to optimistic.

Comment: @wonglik I think you're working under false assumptions. Being W3C standards compliant doesn't mean something will work in all current and future browsers. Whether or not you use GWT, you will still have to test on new browser releases and you will, more likely than not, have to make some changes and ship a new version of your app. But if you use GWT, and GWT has already released a new version compatible with the new browser, then your new release may simply require recompiling with the new version of GWT.

Comment: @isaac I agree that standards compliant does not guarantee your html will be correctly rendered in all browsers but all modern browsers pass Acid2 (IE pass from version 8). So if my browser correctly renders correct HTML today it will in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but if you set the doctype to the experimental HTML5 you can see that it reduces to 1 error: the missing title in the head. Maybe there just aiming for HTML5 and don't care about the current incompliance.